# React js Antd renders erroneous layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using **Antd** for a `ReactJs` project, but I saw that there is an erroneous rendering in the components layout.
Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Test extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.test}>
        <p>This is a text</p>
        <img style={styles.image}
          src={require('../../assets/images/test.png')}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

var styles = {
  test: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor:'#334455'
  },
}
```

Which results in this rendering

[image]

As you can see they are not aligned horizontally. 
But if I comment this line inside my `App.js`

```
// import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

Then everything renders perfectly

[image]

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: your `ntd/dist/antd.css` file may have some css which affects the layout of your elements

Comment: @HridayModi fair enough, there was a `margin-top:0` for `p`. I removed it and now it works pretty fine. Thanks, I'll accept your answer if you write one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `ntd/dist/antd.css` file may have some css(i.e. for image OR p or div tag) which affects the layout of your elements